# Atom SFTP - Adobe Business Catalyst

Tags: atom-editor, business-catalyst

Could someone please help me with setting up Atom sftp to connect to an Adobe Business Catalyst site.

I've installed the Atom sftp-deployment package

Created this deployment-config.json file (it's currently the only thing in the site folder in my documents):

```
{

"type": "sftp",

"host": "mytrialsitename.worldsecuresystems.com",

"username": "mytrialsitename.worldsecuresystems.com/myemail",

"password": "mypassword",

"port": 22,

"remotePath": "/",

"uploadOnSave": false

}
```

I've tried it with / at the end of username.

In the sftp-deployment package settings I've tried changing the "Path to private SSH key" from Default to this for the BC European data centre as I'm in UK:

ssh-rsa 1024 22:84:42:39:2f:d9:5a:5c:74:ab:99:c8:f5:4b:ce:0f

I tried the other EU data centre number as well. I got these from this Adobe BC site - https://docs.worldsecuresystems.com/user-manual/site-design/connecting-to-your-site-using-sftp

And in the sftp-deployment package I've unchecked the Upload on save to match the json file.

If I right click the file in the Project column then FTP/SFTP > Download Selection or Upload Selection, all I'm getting is a loading symbol spinning round for ever.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of searching. SFTP-Deployment Package doesn't work at the moment for the Atom version I'm using 1.19.2. So I've switched to Remote-FTP and it works a treat.